# getting this error -> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, future

```
  _buildPincode()  {
    final _pcode =  getUserLocation(_areaname);
    FutureBuilder<Widget>(
        builder: (context, snapshot)  {
      return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Pincode'),
    onSaved: (String? _pcode){
    _pincode = _pcode!;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to get the pincode using the area name that a user will enter

Comment: which line is giving you this error?

Comment: Please,mention  which line actually throws this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not returning anything in `_buildPincode`:

```
_buildPincode() {
  final _pcode =  getUserLocation(_areaname);
  return FutureBuilder<Widget>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Pincode'),
        onSaved: (String? _pcode) {
          _pincode = _pcode!;
        });
  });
}
```